# What is the unit of sizes in a Portable Executable?

Tags: windows, dll, portable-executable

Using `dumpbin` I can see that my, e.g., `.data` section is 261C6294 "big":

[image: Screenshot of dumpbin output]

However, I couldn't figure out what the unit of that size is: bits, bytes, pages (of which size), ...

I've checked various places like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format but still am not the wiser.

Thanks!

Comment: It's simply bytes (hexadecimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of David Trapp the answer is: bytes (hexadecimally formatted).